# Как реализовать вертикальный каталог каналов?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Хочу сделать сбоку слева блок, в котором будут кружки каналов для навигации(как в дискорде короче). Как реализовать, чтобы они не ломались и оставались пропорциональными? Код выглядит примерно так:

```
<div class="channel-list">
  <div class="channel">
    <a href="#!">
      1 канал
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="channel">
    <a href="#!">
      2 канал
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Приведите Ваш CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Я не совсем понял что ты имеешь ввиду, что значит

> чтобы они не ломались и оставались пропорциональными?

Есть css свойство aspect-ratio,

`aspect-ratio: 1/1`

Свойство сохраняет пропорции элемента ( в данном случае 1 к 1 ), например, при изменении только ширины высота будет также меняться автоматически. Я не пробовал указывать разные значения ширины и высоты, полагаю что какое то свойство ( ширина или высота ) перестанет учитываться.